# Quirky Winforms Font Behavior On MouseHover

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, user-interface

So I'm working on a basic subclass of Label that supports editing. The editing part works fine--I insert a text box with no background color or border on click, commit changes on enter or loss of focus.

The little thing that's giving me trouble is related to some basic font styling. The label is to underline with the MouseHover event (like a hyperlink) and then lose the underline afterwards. Most of the time, it works, but occasionally, the MouseHover will cause the font to revert to the Winforms default--8pt sans-serif--instead of performing the operation.

Here's the event handler:

```
    void BWEditableLabel_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _fontBeforeHover = Font;
        Font hoverFont = new Font(
            _fontBeforeHover.FontFamily.Name,
            _fontBeforeHover.Size,
            _fontBeforeHover.Style | FontStyle.Underline
            );
        Font = hoverFont;
    }
```

Some of you may observe that the last line doesn't simply say:

`Font = new Font(Font, Font.Style | FontStyle.Underline)`

I tried that, and the problem came about. The current version before you was an attempt that I made to resolve the issue.

Comment: I'm stumped. Also, maybe you should override the OnFontChanged and cache he Underlined and non-underlined font, that way you don't have to make a new Font every time the mouse hovers over it.

Comment: Don't know if this concerns your issue, but you should avoid to heavily create new font objects. Instead create the 2 different font instance you whish to use and toggle between those.

Comment: Are you guys saying I should avoid creating a new font every time the hover happens? Is that because it's an expensive run-time operation?

Comment: Its because Font objects are windows resources that are limited to some maximum. Even if your font object goes out of scope after leaving your handler function, the actual windows resource might not be freed immediately.

Comment: Definitely a good point--thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it, though it feels like a bit of a patch instead of the cleanest solution. I did away with `_fontBeforeHover` and created `_originalFont`. I then overrode the `Font` property of the label and in the setter, set `_originalFont` to whatever the label is being set to. Then, in my `MouseHover` and `MouseLeave` events, I used a new method, `SetFont()` to change the font. Within `SetFont()`, I assign `base.Font` instead of using the overridden property. If I used the overridden property, I'd always be reassigning `_originalFont` to whatever I change the label's font to during the events.

Sure would be nice if I didn't need all that extra code, though :-)

I'm definitely open to more suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use the MouseEnter and MouseLeave events? MouseEnter sets it to underlined and MouseLeave reverts it.

Comment: Just curious--is this suggestion just a "try and see" or does MouseEnter generally behave a bit differently in relation to these sorts of things?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the double answer, but maybe you might want to consider drawing the text yourself via DrawString in the paint event, that way you're not setting the Font property. The Font property gets it's value from the Parent's font unless explicitly set.

Answer (score 0):

On your user control create a mousehover Event for your control like this, (or other event type) like this

```
    private void picBoxThumb_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Call Parent OnMouseHover Event
        OnMouseHover(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

On your WinFrom which hosts the UserControl have this for the UserControl to Handle the MouseOver

```
this.thumbImage1.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.ThumbnailMouseHover);
```

Which calls this method on your  WinForm

```
    private void ThumbnailMouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ThumbImage thumb = (ThumbImage) sender;

    }
```

Where ThumbUmage is the type of usercontrol